# Getting error in OAuth authentication

Tags: android-twitter

```
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221): Error during OAUth retrieve request token
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(OAuthRequestTokenTask.java:37)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask.doInBackground(OAuthRequestTokenTask.java:1)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (maybe missing INTERNET permission)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:187)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:872)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1019)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:317)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:129)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.sendRequest(CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.java:64)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:177)
04-12 15:19:29.317: E/com.qa.android.OAuthRequestTokenTask(221):    ... 9 more
```

This the error i got.
please help me out of these.

Answer (score 0):

You need the internet permission for that action. You can add this permission to your manifest file.